# Installation issues of causalimpact in R

Tags: r

I followed this instruction from google website about installing causalimpact:

```
install.packages("devtools")*

library(devtools)

devtools::install_github("google/CausalImpact")
```

*These codes however gives the following error:*

> Warning: package 'xts' was built under R version 3.2.5
>
> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),
>   versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :    there is no package called 'Rcpp'
>
> ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'CausalImpact'
>
> removing
>   'C:/Users/grace/Documents/R/R-3.2.4revised/library/CausalImpact'
>
> Error: Command failed (1)**

Has anyone encountered this problem and can you give the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Following code solved it:

```
install.packages("devtools")*
library(devtools)
install.packages("bsts")
install.packages("xts")
library("bsts")
library("xts")
install.packages("DBI")
library("DBI")
install.packages("Rcpp")
library("Rcpp")
install.packages("magrittr")
library("magrittr")
install.packages("tibble")
library("tibble")
install.packages("gtable")
library("gtable")
install.packages("scales")
library("scales")
devtools::install_github("google/CausalImpact", force = TRUE)
```

The problem was that some libraries were not installed and they are required for Causal impact package.